# How to authenticate an ALB with Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-application-load-balancer

I have an internet-facing ALB in front of my service (ECS Fargate + FastAPI hosted in private subnets of a VPC, although I don't think it's relevant to the issue). I tested it works well before I tried to configure authentication (`curl -X GET -k https://xxxxxxxxxx.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com/health` gave me the correct response, and the `-k` was because I used a self-signed certificate).

I'm following [this official document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/listener-authenticate-users.html#authentication-flow) to set up authentication using Cognito. I *think* I have followed all steps. Now I try `curl -X GET -k -H "Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" https://xxxxxxxxxx.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com/health` where the `xxxxxxxxxx` is the access token I received from an `initiate_auth` call to Cognito. However, I got an `401 Authorization Required`.